# Python Scrapy, xpath selector blocked,

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying scrape a table from oddsportal (https://www.oddsportal.com/soccer/europe/uefa-nations-league/results/#). My end goal is to to extract participants and odds.

All other "response.xpath" works but from the line "colgroup" no xpath selector works. I guess this line is some sort of barrier to access(?). Please have a look at screenshots. xpath selector works before the line the line "colgroup" but doesn't work after the line.

P.S. if you want to run scrapy yourself for the website, you may need to solve request 404 issue by modifying "setting.py".

[Before the "colgroup" line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F8Uh2.png)

[Before the "colgroup" line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3O69q.png)

[After the "colgroup" line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8G14.png)

[After the "colgroup" line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S8yZe.png)

Comment: This site renders through JavaScript, you can't scrape it the way you're trying.

Comment: Thanks @Hanna. Can you explain a bit more please? I can see numeric odds data in dev tool, but still I cannot scrape in this way, do you mean? If so, which way should I have a look to scrape them? Thanks!

Comment: Your browser shows the website after it renders through JavaScript that is why you see the table and all the data in the dev tools try get the page source and search for the data in it -you won't find it-.  what really happens is that the HTML page has a script tag containing JavaScript that makes a request to an API to get the data and modify the HTML automatically.  when you make a request using `requests` or `scrapy` you only get the HTML page.  so the right way to scrape this site is by capturing their API or using Selenium.

Comment: Thanks @Hanna. I will start to read about those two options then :)